# Dapper - how to work with dynamic objects

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

I'm using Dapper to query from SQL and have a dynamic query as such:

```
var returns = conn.Query(dynamicQuery);
```

When I then cycle through the results, I would like to find out what the type of date I am handling is so I tried doing the following:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    MessageBox.Show(result.GetType().ToString());
}
```

But it always fails on the `MessageBox` with the error `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`.

If I use this instead:

```
var returns = conn.Query<object>(dynamicQuery);
```

Then the command works, but it gives me a `Dapper.SqlMapper+DapperRow` object type.

How can I find the type of a `dynamic` variable?

Comment: Have you tried `foreach (var result in results.Where(r=>r!=null))`

Comment: Same error, also I'm only returning one row on my query which I know is of data type `DateTime`

Comment: null ref means nothing returned. Have you tried checking returns!=null first?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the dynamic api, it is expected that you know the shape in terms of columns, i.e.

```
foreach(dynamic row in query) {
    int id = row.Id;
    //...
}
```

However, each row also implements `IDictionary<string, object>` if things are less clear: so cast to that.

Alternatively, if (comments) you know there is a single cell of type date time:

```
var when = conn.Query<DateTime>(...).Single();
```

Comment: If there is no result, will a FirstOrDefault return null into when?

Comment: @arviman yes, `Query(...).FirstOrDefault()` or `QueryFirstOrDefault(...)` will return `null` if there are zero rows.

Comment: @MarcGravell I confirmed this works. Thanks for the QueryFirstOrDefault tip. Your knowledge is amazing.

Answer (score -4):

```
int RecCount = ((dynamic)res[0]).RecCount;
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score -5):

```
Friend Function GetDepartment(ByVal DateFrom As String, ByVal DateTo As String)
    Dim xSQL As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    xSQL.AppendLine("SELECT SUM(a.Quantity ) AS quantity, ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    SUM(a.TotalAmount ) AS totalamount, ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    a.ProductID, ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    c.DepartmentID, ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    a.LongName, ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    c.Department ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("FROM Transaction01Details a ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    INNER JOIN Product00header b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    INNER JOIN Department00header c ON b.DepartmentID = c.DepartmentID ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("WHERE (a.Tag4 = 'i') ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("    AND (a.TransDate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2) ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("GROUP BY a.ProductID ")
    xSQL.AppendLine("ORDER BY a.LongName ")

    ' Lambda Expression
    Dim lambda = cn.Query(xSQL.ToString, New With {.Date1 = DateFrom, .Date2 = DateTo}).Select(Function(p) New With {.ProductID = CStr(p.ProductID), _
                                                                                    .DepartmentID = CStr(p.DepartmentID), _
                                                                                    .LongName = CStr(p.LongName), _
                                                                                    .Department = CStr(p.Department), _
                                                                                    .Quantity = CDec(p.Quantity), _
                                                                                    .TotalAmount = CDec(p.TotalAmount)}).ToList

    ' Linq Expression
    Dim linq = (From p In cn.Query(xSQL.ToString, New With {.Date1 = DateFrom, .Date2 = DateTo})
                Select New With {.ProductID = CStr(p.ProductID), ' Note, All p.Object is also dynamic
                                 .DepartmentID = CStr(p.DepartmentID), 
                                 .LongName = CStr(p.LongName),
                                 .Department = CStr(p.Department),
                                 .Quantity = CDec(p.Quantity),
                                 .TotalAmount = CDec(p.TotalAmount)}).ToList


    ' in linq, no need to declare function and also no need to put this  --- >  _ to continue the statement


End Function
```

You can Achieve dynamic mapping thru this in visual basic.. i gave the fish.. its your turn to cook in